# Message Signing using MyCrypto and MyEtherWallet

Tags: erc-20, myetherwallet, mycrypto

I am trying to update my Token information and it is asking me to sign the message using either MyCrypto and MyEther Wallet and proceed. Unfortunately tried both and both of them are not creating signatures. Can any one help or is there anyway I can write my own code to generate the signature?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to sign a message there is a link in the bottom right of MyEtherWallet.com that will take you to a message signer/verify page [link](https://www.myetherwallet.com/signmsg.html).

Comment: Yes, but when try to sign and provide my address `$scope.wallet.getHWType is not a function` error comes

Answer (score 0):

Try the new beta release of MyCrypto. You can find the signing page over at https://mycrypto.com/sign-and-verify-message/sign, this should resolve your issue.

Comment: tried that its broken and doesn't sign anything